# How to delete controls from telerik Rad Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, spreadsheet

I am working on a `telerik RadSpreadsheet`. I want to delete the controls(buttons like undo, redo, save,etc..)
from the spreadsheet and want to add my own controls. can some one suggest me how can I achieve this, I am using `telerik` for the first time.
[image]

Comment: Somebody please suggest me, how can i do this.

Comment: I find a way how to delete controls from **Rad Spreadsheet** toolbar.                 
`   var $ = $ || $telerik.$;
    function f() {
    var spread = $find("<%= RadSpreadsheet1.ClientID%>");
    var homeToolbar = $(spread.get_element()).find(".RadToolBar")[0].control; 
     homeToolbar.findItemByText("Undo").hide();
     homeToolbar.findItemByText("Redo").hide();  }
    Sys.Application.add_load(f);` Still don't know how to add controls to the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

This way I could use and hide but I guess it's the restriction to add new.

```xml
<telerik:RadSpreadsheet runat="server" ID="ExcelImportPreviewSpreadsheet" ColumnWidth="64" Skin="Metro" Width="100%">
    <Toolbar>
        <telerik:SpreadsheetToolbarTab>
            <telerik:SpreadsheetToolbarGroup>
                <telerik:SpreadsheetTool Visible ="false" />
            </telerik:SpreadsheetToolbarGroup>
        </telerik:SpreadsheetToolbarTab>
    </Toolbar>
</telerik:RadSpreadsheet>
```